# Issue with getting information from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Ok so here is what I am trying to do,  I have a Item collection that holds a users items along with price quantity and description.  I have also created a collection called soldItems that will store information about a sold item once the user inputs the required data and submits the form.  I am not sure if I am doing this correctly to begin with and I have been trying to research this but I don't exactly know what I am looking for.

Here is the code I have so far

```
router.post("/item/:id", middleware.isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  Item.findById(req.params.id, (err, item) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    var soldItem = {
      id: req.params.id,
      item: req.item.name,
      askPrice: req.item.price
    };
    var soldPrice = req.body.soldPrice;
    var soldQuantity = req.body.soldQuantity;
    var itemSold = {
      soldItem: soldItem,
      soldPrice: soldPrice,
      soldQuantity: soldQuantity
    };
    SoldItem.create(itemSold, (err, newlyCreated) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        item.soldItems.push(newlyCreated);
        item.save();
        req.flash("success", "Item Sold");
        res.redirect("back");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

So... Item.findById(req.params.id) works because I am pulling the ObjectId from the url.  However, how would I be able to use req.item._id.  Because the issue I am having is when I am trying to get req.item.name and req.item.price I am being told that it cannot read property 'name' or 'price' of undefined.  How can I get that information?

Comment: You mean the `item` from here `Item.findById(req.params.id, (err, item)`? Then that's just `item` and NOT `req.item`. So `item.name` etc. I think you are completely missing the difference between the "request object" and the "object from the collection" which you just retrieved with the marked statement.

Comment: You're right, I am ... So I got that to work and now I am getting an error that says: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined ... So now to figure that out.

Comment: @Darrell can you post your SoldItem schema definition?